# How to add Transition Effects to JavaScript toggle menu?

Tags: javascript, css

I want to give a smooth transition effect (like the ease in out or fade) to a simple JavaScript toggle mobile menu.

I have tried it achieving by CSS Transition effect but no luck but I am sure it can be either achieved by CSS or JavaScript. I think using CSS would be better unless it's impossible.

Here is the code:

```
var toggle  = document.getElementById("toggle");
var content = document.getElementById("content");

toggle.addEventListener("click", function() {
  content.style.display = (content.dataset.toggled ^= 1) ? "block" : "none";
});
```

```
#content{
  display:none;
}
```

```
<button id="toggle">TOGGLE</button>
<div id="content">Some content...</div>
```

The content should be Show/Hide smoothly with ease in out or fade in/out effect. How is it possible?

Comment: you can't fade from/to `display:none`. you would have to transition the `opacity` to fade it. you can use another technique to mimic `display:none`, like `left:-300vh`, and slightly delay the opacity transition.

Answer (score 2):

here is your requiured solution. Jquery makes your task easy and understandable.

```js
var toggle  = document.getElementById("toggle");
var content = document.getElementById("content");

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#toggle").click(function(){
    $("#content").fadeToggle("slow");
  /*   $("#div3").fadeOut(3000); */
  });
});
```

```css
#content {
  width:80px;
  height:80px;
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="toggle">TOGGLE</button>
<div id="content">Some content...</div>
```

Comment: No I can't add jQuery. Sorry!

Comment: I need the solution with existing code or similar JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot animate `display: none`, because you remove the element entirely.
Instead you could try and use a combination of `visibility: visible` --> `visibility: hidden`, and `opacity: 1` --> `opacity: 0`.